# Placement of Call-To-Action buttons to request an account on a corporate login page for an internal site?

Tags: forms, interaction-design, login

I am building an internal blog for our company to use. In my wireframe I placed the button at the bottom to make it out of the way for people that already have an account.

But prominent enough where a new user knows what to do if they need an account. 
[image: login wireframe]

The current plan I have right now is to have that section expand down to reveal a form where they can enter their information. So is this a good plan?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Login page design is basically a solved problem at this point.

The three different approaches [that I see](http://dzineblog.com/2009/03/interface-design-inspiration-36-beautiful-login-pageform-designs.html):

1. Login primary action with tabs to get to the sign-up secondary action
2. Login primary action with a link below the form to get to the sign-up secondary action
3. Side-by-side sign-up and log in

Your approach looks more like (2), except that the request account (sign-up) is a button instead of a link. It should be a link because the sign-up is not the main call to action here. It's bigger and green and could cause people to mistakenly click on it as a submit button.

Comment: Ok great point about the button color and size.